# Politely saying "we will perform the safety test after finishing the modernisation work"

Tags: word-usage

I am writing an email to reply the client and I want to tell him that when we finish the modernisation work, we will perform the safety test. How can I say it politely?

- We will perform the safety test after **finishing** the modernisation work. Or
- We will perform the safety test after the modernisation work **is finished**. Or
- We will perform the safety test after we **finished** the modernisations work.

Comment: I changed the title to match the body and bolded some of the text to highlight the differences. Did you mean "modernisation**s**" in the third one? You can [edit] your post anytime. See [Contributor's Guide (Formatting)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4799/36187) for formatting tips. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples of asking questions.

Comment: [after we finish]

Answer (score 1):

> We will perform the safety test after finishing the modernisation work.

Fine.

"modernisation" is a British spelling.

> We will perform the safety test after the modernisation work is finished.

Good.

> We will perform the safety test after we finished the modernisations work. *

"modernisations" should be "modernisation".  "finished" should be "finish" or "have finished".

Answer (score -1):

All your variants are quite OK.

I only want to bring a little improvement. I built this structure based on my own experience.

> We **plan to** perform the safety test after finishing **the work on modernization**.

"Plan" is better, because the future is not open and visible like a book. Even if the chances are small, there is still a chance that the safety test will not be done. Think Earth quake, tsunami, asteroid...